# How big is the serial input buffer on Windows?

Tags: windows, winapi, serial-port, msdn

I've looked through MSDN and the internet at large, but I have found no definitive answer. How large (in bytes) is the input buffer for serial communication in the Win32 API?

Comment: The MSDN article on the Serial port describes optional hardware buffers ( https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff802693.aspx ) but otherwise does not go into detail, suggesting to me that the input buffer is in hardware (possibly part of the UART?) and thus not the OS's responsibility, and that you would need a hardware-specific driver to interrogate the device for its buffer stats.

Comment: You can use [`SetupComm()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363439.aspx) to specify custom buffer sizes, though the driver is not required to honor them: "*The device driver receives the recommended buffer sizes, but is free to use any input and output (I/O) buffering scheme, as long as it provides reasonable performance and data is not lost due to overrun (except under extreme circumstances). For example, the function can succeed even though the driver does not allocate a buffer, as long as some other portion of the system provides equivalent functionality.*"

Comment: @RemyLebeau, thanks for the info. So this means that the input buffer could be any size, right? If you re-write your comment as an answer, I'll happily accept it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if there's a universal default size for all versions of Windows, but my research determined that you can call [GetCommProperties()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-getcommproperties) to find out the current sizes of the transmit and receive buffers. I haven't tried that myself yet, but I intend to use it to find out the default size on the versions of Windows I'm writing for at the moment.